# How to set up a donation add on for purchase in UWP app?

Tags: uwp

There seems to be a lack of information for this scenario as well as good recent examples.

My scenario is a simple donation to allow users to donate from a certain amounts (like 0.99 1.99, 3.99 etc), one or more times if they choose.

In the developer dashboard, for my app I created an add on.  I chose

1) Developer Managed Add on
(I chose this so more version of the OS are supported as opposed to store managed which require certain version of Windows 10 or later)

2) The next step is the set up properties for the add on, now this is where I'm not sure what to enter.

[image]

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/uwp/publish/set-your-add-on-product-id#product-type) states

> For most add-ons, the content type should be Electronic software
>   download.

So that's what I chose.  Next is the keywords and the Custom Developer Data.  I read the documentation, but really I don't understand what these are used for?  How are they used by my app? By the store?  It doesn't really show a real life example how it gets used by the code (if at all).

Also is there an example of how the following fields are used in the store - where the customer sees these?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These managed consumables are managed by you. The store will report the presence of the add-ons when you request it using the api. When you publish the add-on, you have the option to specify if it's available to be purchased directly from the store. If so, the store gives you the ability to add keywords so that your sub-products appear in search results in the Microsoft Store app or Microsoft Store website.

You also have the option to only allow these add-ons to be purchased from the main app you built. If so, the keywords are pointless because your add-ons will not appear in search results. They will only be available from your app's code using the [StoreContext API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storecontext).

As for title/description, these appear in the receipt for the user. When they buy your add-ons, they will get an email confirmation of what they bought and you can put custom title/description there to give the user a more thorough explanation of what they bought instead of having an ugly unique ID.

The same goes for the icon. It appears in the email receipt... to make it pretty. And I think it also appears in search results if your requested it.

The custom developer data, that's going to be raw text data that appears in your code when you call the API. So, when you call the API and ask for all the available add-ons from your app's code, it will give you all the details of your add-ons plus the custom developer data. You can put anything you want in there, including JSON. You can parse it and create a different experience for the user. This is optional. Leave it blank if you don't care. This value cannot be modified by the app. It's a static value that can only be modified in the dev center.

The good thing about custom developer data is you can alter the effect of an add-on by changing values in that field. For example:

```
{
   Level: 1
}
```

or

```
{
   Level: 2
}
```

You don't have to republish your add-on. Your app will react to the new "level" value, assuming you coded it right :)

Comment: So the app allows you to get the custom developer data, update a value inside it, then save it back without having to republish the add on, is this right? Also, is this data user specific? I.e.each user has their own custom developer data

Comment: @erotavlas,  no, that's incorrect. The custom developer data is just data you update using the dev center website. It's intended to send different information to the application so that it reacts to it. Like my example, imagine you had a game and you can manually change what level they unlock using the custom dev data. The app cannot change that. Only read it. And it's the same for all users.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very help sample that shows how to code in-app purchases and then check if the user has purchased a particular license. It's at: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Licensing-API-Sample-19712f1a. (This is an older sample, but gives you want you want on UWP). It also explains how to set up consumable in-app purchases in the Developer hub.

Using the license check, you can verify that the user has made a donation, if you want to show some UI based on that. This license check is on the LicenseInformation class.

Calling LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses["Donation"].IsActive will give that information.

Comment: OK thanks, I was reluctant to use those old samples, since I thought much may have changes in the api.  But I will check it out..

Comment: Note: You need to use CurrentAppSimulator when testing locally, debugging your app. This simulates what would happen if a license were purchased. The calls to the live service are on CurrentApp.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone reading this, the Microsoft Store app certification policies might have changed in the meantime.
This is from a failed submission report:

> **App Policies:** 10.8.2 Third Party IAP API - Charity & Sweepstakes
>
> **Notes To Developer**
> You must use a secure third-party payment API. Apps may not use the Microsoft Store in-app purchase API for charitable donations.

So this means it is not allowed to use the in-app payments for donations! If you implement the above, the app submission might fail.